# How to get same column values to make multiple columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5.6

I don't know if my question is valid or not but I'm working on an attendance system, and I want to get some output for my project.

I have an attendance table that holds three columns: emp_id, atten_type and date. The atten_type column can contain one of three values; that is 'present', 'absent' and 'leave'.

Now, I want the output like this:

[image: i got only one value like count(atten_type) from table where atten_type = "present"]

Comment: its easier to be explicit like below rather than creating a table based on your contents. Pivot tables are very horrible and if you know the atten_type values up front use them.

Comment: Please provide source data which must produce the output you show...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So grouping by emp_id, month and suming the count based on `atten_type`?

```
SELECT emp_id,
    SUM(IF(atten_type='present',1,0) as 'atten_type as present',
    SUM(IF(atten_type='leave',1,0) as 'atten_type as leave',
    SUM(IF(atten_type='absent',1,0) as 'atten_type as absent',
    MONTH(`date`) as 'month'
FROM
    attendance
GROUP BY emp_id, `month`
```

Comment: Author claims that DBMS is MySQL. So you do not need in IF() and can use simple `SUM(atten_type='present')`